# Ending a video in HTML using JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am displaying a YouTube video on my html page using JavaScript.

How do I hide the video and retain the page that displayed the video using JavaScript?

I need to hide the video on a button click.

My code looks like this:

```
function addVideo(qId){
    alert("a video");
    var $videoComp = '<div class="vid" id="myytplayer"><iframe id="ifr" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ac7KhViaVqc" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div><div class ="main"><button class="btn btn-success" id="one" >Close video</button></div>';
$('.create-elem').append($videoComp);
$(".main").click(function(){
        //$(".vid").hide();
        //$("#one").hide();
    function stopthevideo(){

        var myPlayer = document.getElementById('myytplayer');
        myPlayer.stopVideo();
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do to identify end of video.

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

myVideo.addEventListener('ended',onVideoEnded,false);

function onVideoEnded(e) {
    if(!e) { e = window.event; }
            // Make your things here
            hideVideo = true;
}
```

Or you can always try work with https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_status

Hope one of these will help you :)

Comment: Thank you.The video ends successfully but it goes back to the previous page after ending.I want the page containing video to stay as it is...

Answer (score 0):

The try to set video position at the ended event:

Save the start time and duration time to variable after `loadedmetadata` event.

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

var videoStartTime = 0;
var videoEndTime = 0;

myVideo.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  videoStartTime = 2;
  videoEndTime = 4;
  this.currentTime = videoStartTime;
}, false);
```

If current time is greater than start time plus end of video time, pauses the video.

```
myVideo.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  if(this.currentTime > videoStartTime + videoEndTime ){
    this.pause();
  }
});
```